# Get the ARN for the API gateway resource that the serverless framework creates within my serverless.yml file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

How can I get the ARN for the API gateway resource that the serverless framework creates within my serverless.yml file?

I want to get the ARN for the API Gateway resource so that I can use it within an IAM policy to perform IAM based authorization on the gateway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The whole ARN for an API is of the [form](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-control-access-using-iam-policies-to-invoke-api.html): `arn:aws:execute-api:region:account-id:api-id/stage/METHOD_HTTP_VERB/Resource-path`). Using `{ "Ref" : "ApiGatewayRestApi" }` ([link](https://forum.serverless.com/t/fixed-how-do-i-get-reference-api-gateway-restapi-id-in-serverless-yml/3397)) within your serverless.yml gives you the apiId.

You can do something like the below (see the Resource section) to convert this to a whole Arn to reference an API:

```
PolicyName: InvokeAPI
PolicyDocument:
  Version: "2012-10-17"
  Statement:
    Effect: "Allow"
    Action: "execute-api:Invoke"
    Resource:
      - Fn::Join:
        - "/"
        - 
          - Fn::Join: [":", ["arn:aws:execute-api", {"Ref": "AWS::Region"}, {"Ref":"AWS::AccountId"}, {"Ref": "ApiGatewayRestApi"}]]
          - "*"
```